# Snowflake UDF behaves differently in Snowflake WebUI and DBeaver

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

I have created a UDF to evaluate each sorted rows to cache value for comparison at the query checks on each rows. The UDF works fine if you run the query as seen below. Correct output is DBeaver screenshot.

Result from DBeaver using Snowflake JDBC provides different output from Snowflake WebUI even though script are the same. The weirdest thing of all is that in DBeaver, you can see the correct output, but if you insert that to a table or "create table as select" the output that comes out are the same as webUI which is wrong.

Snowflake UI
[image]

DBeaver UI
[image]

Comment: You will need to help us reproduce this problem. All I see in the screenshots is a difference in `IS_NEW_ROW`, but where's the code and input data? Please help us help you.

Comment: Hi Felipe, I will send this link to our SF account manager so we can have discussion on tihs. It is better show this on a meeting. Btw, irregardless of what data it is. As you can see both queries are the same. I accessing the same number of rows(32) for both queries and they are the same data. It is the same table. Same schema. Same DB. Same warehouse. Same Role. And Same function. Just different IDE.

Comment: Yes. But I can't reproduce anything just by watching two pictures. Contacting support is a better alternative if you can't share enough context here for Stack Overflow to help.