# Snowflake UDF behaves differently while using "LIMIT"

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a UDF that evaluates rows. It works fine in most cases, but sometimes it acts weird. See example below. These are exactly the same query. One with "Limit" and the other without. The total record count here is 32 but I add Limit 1000 just for the example. Would you know why the these two queries behave differently?

Without Limit - Wrong Output
[image]

With Limit - Correct Output - Again total records is 32.
[image]

Comment: Please post `ER_ROW_EVALUATOR` code. I guess you have undeterministic code somewhere(ROW_NUMBER/ORDER BY ....).

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, check on my other problem related to this. Same code. Same table. Same DB. Same warehouse. Same Role. Same functions. And output is different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67378722/snowflake-udf-behaves-differently-in-snowflake-webui-and-dbeaver?noredirect=1#comment119096099_67378722

Comment: Given the code that Lukasz was able to finally obtain: Avoid using a global state in a JS UDF, because the results are non-deterministic. Please post a new question - with code, sample input, and output so we can write a deterministic UDF that can do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

The function code:

```
create or replace function new_row_evaluator
       (b varchar, m datetime, f DATETIME, t datetime ) 
returns string
language javascript
as '
if (typeof tmp_barcode === "undefined") {
    tmp_barcode = B;
    tmp_fromdate = F;
    tmp_todate = T;
    return "1";
}
if (tmp_barcode == B) {
    if (M >= tmp_fromdate && M <= tmp_todate) {
        return "0";
    } else {
        tmp_fromdate = F;
        tmp_todate = T;
        return "1";
    }
} else {
    tmp_barcode = B;
    tmp_fromdate = F;
    tmp_todate = T;
    return "1";
} ';
```

I assume that the UDF is using some sort of global state `tmp_barcode`.

> **[Global state](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-js.html#global-state)**
>
> Snowflake usually preserves the JavaScript global state between iterations of a UDF. **However, you should not rely on previous modifications to the global state being available between function calls.** Additionally, you should not assume that all rows will execute within the same JavaScript environment.
>
> a recommended pattern is to guarantee that relevant code is evaluated only once, using JavaScript’s global variable semantics. For example:
>
> ```
> var setup = function() {
> /* SETUP LOGIC */
> };
>
> if (typeof(setup_done) === "undefined") {
>   setup();
>   setup_done = true;  // setting global variable to true
> }
> ```
>
> **Note that this mechanism is only safe for caching the effects of code evaluation. It is not guaranteed that after an initialization the global context will be preserved for all rows, and no business logic should depend on it.**

Comment: I actually do not follow your logic. Just to follow your example. Run that in Snowflake WebUI and then run same query in your DBeaver or any SQL tool you use. Check if the the output are the same. My result is different. Now try returning different outcome from your example without doing any changes. Btw, there is no windows function inside my function. It is just doing comparison.

Comment: `create or replace function new_row_evaluator(b varchar, m datetime, f DATETIME, t datetime )
  returns string
  language javascript
  as '
 if (typeof tmp_barcode === "undefined") {
  tmp_barcode = B;
  tmp_fromdate = F;
  tmp_todate = T;
  return "1";
 }   
 
if (tmp_barcode == B) {
   if (M >= tmp_fromdate && M <= tmp_todate) {
 return "0";  
 } else {
      tmp_fromdate = F;
      tmp_todate = T;
      return "1";
    }
 } else {
 tmp_barcode = B;
 tmp_fromdate = F;
 tmp_todate = T;
 return "1";
 }
   ';`

Comment: Apologies, I am no expert in posting here. Let me figure out how to post the code properly.

Comment: @davidm I guess the issue is global state

Comment: Yes. I do not know how long it holds the global state of a variable. The weird part of this is that if you do `select ...` using function it works fine and then when you start to load it to a static table by doing `insert` or `create table` outcomes are different. Anyway, I have reached out to SF support. LIMIT part is still a mystery to me.

Comment: @davidm Please post an answer, once you get it :)